# Maximum of divisor function ratio over an interval

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Given a positive integer $n$, recall that that the value of the divisor function $\sigma$ at $n$ is defined to be the sum of all the divisors of $n$; in symbols:
$$
\sigma(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} d.
$$

> Is there an efficient way to determine the maximum of $\sigma(n)/n$ for $n \in [a,b] \cap \Bbb{Z}$?

Here by efficient I mean anything faster than actually computing $\sigma(n)/n$ for all $n$ in the interval.

Answer (score 1):

You can say some things, but perhaps not in any great detail; the "high water marks" of the expression $\sigma(n)/n$ occur at the [superabundant numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superabundant_number), so in any interval of the form $[a,b]$ the ratio will be maximized by the largest superabundant number in that interval (provided one exists).

The bad news is that there is not a great deal of control over the prime factorizations of the superabundant numbers, though perhaps you will be able to get enough of a speedup with what little is [easily known](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1944-056-00/S0002-9947-1944-0011087-2/S0002-9947-1944-0011087-2.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. This already allowed me to halve the search space, since it turns out that all superabundant numbers other than $1$ are even. However, at the moment I cannot find any other sufficient conditions that would allow me to speed up the computation even further.